# How to access value of an element in xml using ansible

Tags: xml, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have below xml

```
<business type="bar">
<name>Tasty Beverage Co.</name>
<beers>
  <beer>Rochefort 10</beer>
  <beer>St. Bernardus Abbot 12</beer>
  <beer>Schlitz</beer>
</beers>
<rating subjective="true">10</rating>
<website>
  <mobilefriendly/>
  <address>http://tastybeverageco.com</address>
</website>
</business>
```

I want to access value of `<rating> </rating>` i.e `10`. I have below ansible code for the same. here i'm using `xml` module to fetch the value.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Read an element's attribute values
    xml:
      path: /tmp/test.xml
      xpath: /business/rating
      content: text
    register: xmlresp

  - name: Show an attribute value
    debug:
      var: xmlresp.matches
```

but this will print as below

```
PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Read an element's attribute values] *******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show an attribute value] ******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  xmlresp.matches:
  - rating: '10'
```

I want only value i.e `10` But its printing `- rating: '10'`. I'm facing a scenario where i have list containing xmls with its full path. I have to use `loop` to iterate over each xml file and fetch required value and store it in another list.

I tried to use `regex_replace` to fetch required value. But dint work

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ xmlresp.matches | map('regex_replace', 'rating ', '') | list }}"
    register: op
```

output :

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - '{u''rating'': u''10''}'
```

Can anyone suggest how to fetch only value without its element name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get values from your registered `xlmresp` variable like this:

```
  - name: Show an attribute value
    debug:
      msg: "{{ xmlresp.matches.0.rating }}"
```

Gives:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "10"
}
```